# Webpage cannot find certain files

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I am building a simple sandbox/practice style website on heroku I am trying to learn nodejs and I am learning Angular. After much hit and miss I got the server to load my home.html page, however it cannot seem to find my vendor scripts. Such as my angular, contollers, and some images/css.

The path I have setup for angular is: `<script src="/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/controller.js"></script>`

This is coming from a localhostconnection by the way, so `http://localhost` Here is an example of what my simple index.js in node looks like:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set("port", (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('views engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.render("home.html");
});
app.listen(app.get("port"), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get("port"));
});
```

this is located in the root of the webfiles and it points to a views folder which includes my home.html (how I got my home page to finally load) However it still says it cannot find my vendor scripts.

These are located inside their own vendor folder that is in the root folder, and the views folder is also its own folder in the root folder the setup is like so:

```
-views
---home.html

-vendor
--some vendor folders(bootstrap etc)
---angularjs.js and other vendor scripts
```

I am sure I am missing something simple here, but I am a beginner with nodejs and still learning at this point. Thank you ahead of time for the help, and let me know if I can offer anymore information.

Comment: what is the path you access this with when you install it on Heroku?

Comment: It's on my C: drive when I work on it, but when I install it is on my dropbox account that I have connected to heroku to load up the page when I am running the local server I use: `http://localhost:5000/`

Comment: so your angular.min does not get included on localhost or on heroku  or both?

Comment: Well I have not redeployed this to the heroku setup yet this is just straight testing on my localhost right now

Comment: try removing that '/' in the beginning where you include vendor script.. change it to like so.. <script src="vendor/angular.min.js"></script> and see if that works for you

Comment: Attempted and it does not seem to have made a difference, the paths remain the same, in my network tab I see: `http://localhost:5000/vendor/angular.min.js` whether that slash is there or not.